# Override UIAppearance property for MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, uiappearance

I am using the UIAppearance protocol to set the background image of UINavigationBar objects throughout my app.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-name"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I would like to override this for instances of MFMailComposeViewController so that the default style navigation bar is displayed. I attempted to use appearanceWhenContainedIn to set this and this works on iOS 5 but *not* on iOS 6.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MFMailComposeViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Am I making an error or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: According to Apple Developer Support: It is a known bug in iOS 7.0.

Comment: this is fixed in iOS 9

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Changing the appearance of a MFMailComposer through normal measures is not possible, but there is a little workaround you can do, which I've used many times before.

Add two methods to the class in which you wish to implement the new look to:

```
- (void)applyComposerInterfaceAppearance
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}

- (void)applyGlobalInterfaceAppearance
{
    // My default color of choice
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Now in your show method, apply the special composer interface changes you'd like to make.

```
- (void)showMailComposer
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) 
    {
        [self applyComposerInterfaceApperance];

        MFMailComposeViewController *viewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        viewController.mailComposeDelegate = delegate;
        [viewController setToRecipients:mailRecepients];
        [viewController setSubject:mailSubject];
        [viewController setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

And in your delegate, change the interface back to the way it was.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    // Do normal mail composer did finish stuff in here
    [self applyGlobalInterfaceAppearance];
}
```

Comment: This is what I do in my own apps too. I have a pair of setAppearance and unsetAppearance methods in my app delegate that I can call anywhere to turn on and off all my UI customizations whenever I need to present a standard prebaked view controller (the mail controller, iPod library picker, etc).

Comment: @Ziconic, could you please tell me how you "unset" your uiappearance properties on the fly? thank you

Comment: in my condition this logic worked with setBarTintColor. not with seTintColor.

Answer (score 2):

The Mail Composer view is run in a different process under iOS 6 and cannot be tampered with directly (since the view is essentially inside another app). You cannot customize what it shows, it's the same for the Twitter & Facebook views.

Here is a more detailed description of remote view controllers: http://oleb.net/blog/2012/10/remote-view-controllers-in-ios-6/

Comment: Even though it is run in a remote process, that is an implementation detail not exposed to the developer; as far as the developer is concerned, it looks the same as before. I would suggest filing a bug if it's not working; I know that the remote view controller mechanism does at least *something* with the UIAppearance mechanism, because I have crash logs down in there. :)

Comment: The main view is indeed in a different process but the navigation bar and the navigation controller it's in are in the same process as your app and are styled according to your UIAppearance customizations.

Comment: @BJHomer I filed a radar. Feel free to dupe. rdar://13490724

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the tintColor on the MFMailComposeViewController instance:

```
[mailInstance.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor someColor]];
```