# MFMailComposeViewController crashing on presentViewController on iOS 10.2

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, messageui

Well, this is very minor issue on which I have already spent couple of hours researching and trying to figure out why the app is crashing.

Let's say I've two view controllers VC1, VC2 and I'm calling `MFMailComposeViewController` from VC2.

So far I have tried transitioning from VC1 to VC2..

1. via `performSegueIdentifier`
2. via `Storyboard ID`
3. via `Storyboard ID` with `UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc2)`

but nothing worked. I even tried embedding `UINavigationViewController` to the VC2 but no luck either.

Below is the `IBAction` method in VC2

```
@IBAction func sendEmail(sender: AnyObject) {
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mailComposerVC = configuredMailComposeViewController()
        presentViewController(mailComposerVC, animated: true, completion: nil) // CRASH
    } else {
        showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}


func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {

    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["abc@abc.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Reg: ")

    return mailComposerVC
}

func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail. Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

All outlets and event references are also good.

Crash log

```
[__NSCFNumber pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000000e5
2017-01-16 16:52:55.887082 Sample[2507:671461] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000000e5'
```

**Solved**:

The issue is with the custom navigation bar. I have reset the `UINavigationBar` appearance when presenting `MFMailComposeViewController` and setting it back on dismiss.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580732/1926291) post helped me solve it.

I have created below two methods in a global file.

```
static func applyGlobalNavigationBarAppearance() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontSize()]
}

static func applyMailNavigationBarAppearance() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange! My guess here is that you have set something (a font?) badly via `UIAppearance` and the mail composer is the first time this appearance property is being referenced. Does your project use UIAppearance (e.g. `UINavigationBar.appearance`)? If so, comment them out for now. See if that fixes the problem, then figure out which call is the culprit.

Comment: Yes, I created a custom navigation bar with custom view, it has to be there in VC2. I agree with what you've said, removing the custom navigation bar, but how can I remove the custom navigation bar only for the mail composer without affecting VC2 bar?

Comment: And yes, it worked when I commented out the `UINavigationBar.appearance()` in `AppDelegate`

Comment: I figured out the solution. This post helped me solve it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580405/override-uiappearance-property-for-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller. Thanks a lot for pointing me to the right direction!